# MS Access DataTime field (General Date) insert query

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have a generic DAL query, that wasnt able to insert date. but now i want to edit it but i cant find how to insert it.
I tried as string, Convert(), Format().. anything, yet i cant seem to find how to do it.
It also must be General format (which is DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS(24h)) but i cant seem to find the right way.

```
        public static void AddRow(string TableName, object[] values)
    {
        DataTable dt = OleDbhelper.fill("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " + TableName);
        if (dt.Columns.Count - 1 == values.Length)
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO " + TableName + " (";
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sql += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "]";
                if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    sql += ",";
                else
                    sql += ") ";
            }
            sql += "VALUES (";
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i + 1].DataType.ToString() == "System.String")
                    sql += "'" + values[i].ToString() + "'";
                else
                    if (dt.Columns[i + 1].DataType.ToString() == "System.DateTime")
                        sql += "CONVERT(" + values[i] + "'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)'"; // This part 
                    else
                        sql += values[i].ToString();
                if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 2)
                    sql += ",";
                else
                    sql += ") ";
            }
            OleDbhelper.Execute(sql);
        }
    }
```

any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Access, use:

```
sql += values[i].ToString("'#'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd hh':'mm':'ss'#'");
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. (ofcourse first i needed to convert values[i] to datetime)